# Ruby - Overload solution for initialize with 3 params

Tags: ruby, constructor-overloading

I'm porting some code from other language to Ruby, in my Class I need to maintain compatibility with those 4 constructors:

```
def initialize(b)
def initialize(a, b)
def initialize(b, c)
def initialize(a, b, c)
```

I was trying this way but it does not work:

```
def initialize(a="", b, c="")
```

Is there a smart solution? I cannot use hash.

Comment: What is the difference between `initialize(a, b)` and `initialize(b, c)`?

Comment: `a`, `b` and `c` are of completely different types.

Comment: Converting code from a statically to dynamically typed language you're either going to have to fundamentally alter some things or implement very ugly, un-Ruby workarounds.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that you want to convert to Ruby but use the conventions of the language you're migrating from.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't make sense to port to Ruby at all. If I can find some rules, then I can automate porting. Is there any tool to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a solution, but well it's ugly!

```
def initialize(*args)
    case (args.length)
        when 1
            super(XXX)
            @y = args[0]
        when 2
            if args[0].kind_of?(A) then
                super(args[0])
                @x = args[0]
                @y = args[1]
            elsif args[0].kind_of?(B) then
                super(XXX)
                @y = args[0]
                @z = args[1]
            end 
        when 3
            super(args[0])
            @x = args[0] 
            @y = args[1]
            @z = args[2]
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use a hash (why not?), and they *must* be `initialize` methods, you're likely out of luck. Without typing or positional information, there's just no way to destructure, say, an array, and determine which argument is which.

IMO the cleanest would be to provide class methods that do the construction and accept the arguments specific to the constructor (factory, in this case).

If the arguments are of different types you could use that information to determine which values are being passed in, I suppose, but IMO that gets pretty ugly pretty fast.

Comment: I cannot use hash because I dont want to rewrite a great # of call to this method. I'm porting code, I'm trying to find the easiest way.

Comment: The arguments are of different types and I think that this could be the only solution... sigh.

Answer (score 2):

If `a,b,c` are completely different types, and always will be, then perhaps something like this:

```
def initialize(*args)
   args.each do |arg| 
      do_a if arg.is_a?(first_type)
      do_b if arg.is_a?(second_type)
      do_c if arg.is_a?(third_type)
   end
end
```

I'll admit, it is not pretty but it should work. 
If you are only wanting 3 params then limit the `each` to only run `3.times`.